# search for a string after character

Tags: php

I know how to search a string after a character such as @.The code of it is using the combination of strcmp and strstr.But how to search a string even if it is not after

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: for example i wanted to search asd.com in a email domain after '@' but the email account maybe @as.asd.com

Comment: strcmp(strstr($email, '@'),"@asd.com") == 0 makes the comparsion but not i wanted:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `strpos`. It gives you the position of a string inside of another string, or false otherwise.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
$position_of_substring = strpos($what_to_search_in, $what_to_search_for);
if( $position_of_substring === false )
{
    echo 'The string does not contain the string you are looking for.';
}
else
{
    echo 'Your substring is at position: ' . $position_of_substring;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the method called 'preg_match'

Here the link to the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Here an example:

```php
$subject = "@as.asd.com";
$subject2 = "@asd.as.com";
$pattern = '/asd.com/';
echo preg_match ($pattern, $subject); // return 1 if does match
echo preg_match ($pattern, $subject2); // return 0 if doesn't match
```

Comment: will it not return 1 even if pattern is before @?

Comment: it return 1 if the $pattern is found in the $subject.

Comment: but OP wants pattern to exists after particular character.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '/asd.com/';
$subject has the string that you want to test
```

Explode subject with the character that you want to search after. eg./ @

> $parts = explode("@", $subject);

Check whether @ exists in string or not. If it does then compare and echo output

```
if(count($parts) == 2)  
    echo preg_match ($pattern, $parts[1]);
```

Refer [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) on official documentation